# Is there a port of SWT 3.6 to WPF?

Tags: java, wpf, swt, porting, directwrite

recently i've been looking for a version of SWT that uses WPF (or DirectWrite) as its renderer.

The last version of SWT ported to WPF that I've found was 3.3.

Anyway, is there any port of SWT 3.6 to WPF?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF support was added in [Eclipse 3.3](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/R3_3/new_and_noteworthy.html), and I couldn't find any reference of it being removed until 3.6, which was discussed [on the mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipse.org-committers/msg00800.html) and in the [bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=293830). It sounds from those posts like the WPF build was never really completed, but that's the latest I've found and is dated January 2010. Interestingly, Direct2D support is listed in the plan for [Eclipse 3.7](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/R3_7/plan.html). I can't find any more information than that, you may want to ask the SWT team what's going on.

It's worth noting of course that SWT works fine on Vista and Windows 7, using the win32 API.